# Java string array scope in a loop

Tags: java, android, scope

This is a rather simple Java scoping question, but I'm pretty new to Java and having trouble figuring this out. Specifically, this is for an Android application, but I'm not sure that matters for this question

I have a method that will take SQLite table data and write it out to a CSV file. Depending on the type of data being passed into the method, I want to write data from a different table:

```
public void exportSubjectData(File outputFile, String subNum, String sensorType) throws IOException, SQLException {

        csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));

        switch (sensorType) {
            case "acc": {
                curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATA_ACC_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE id = " + subNum, null);
                String arrStr[] = {curCSV.getString(0), curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2),
                        curCSV.getString(3), curCSV.getString(4)};
                break;
            }
            case "gyro": {
                curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATA_GYRO_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE id = " + subNum, null);
                String arrStr[] = {curCSV.getString(0), curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2)};
                break;
            }
        }

        csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());

        while (curCSV.moveToNext()) {
            csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
        }

        csvWrite.close();
        curCSV.close();
    }
```

My problem is that depending on the `sensorType` being passed in, I want to 1) select from a different table and 2) write out a different number of columns. I'm declaring and intializing `arrStr` in the `switch` block, but when I try to write each column to the CSV, the `while` block doesn't have access to `arrStr`. Presumably this is a scoping problem. Whats the correct way to solve this problem?

When I try to declare `arrStr` outside of the switch I get an unexpected token error:

```
    String[] arrStr;

    switch (sensorType) {
        case "acc": {
            curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATA_ACC_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE id = " + subNum, null);
            arrStr[] = {curCSV.getString(0), curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2),curCSV.getString(3), curCSV.getString(4)};
            break;
        }
        case "gyro": {
            curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATA_GYRO_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE id = " + subNum, null);
            arrStr[] = {curCSV.getString(0), curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2),curCSV.getString(3), curCSV.getString(4)};
            break;
        }
    }
```

I have also tried the following approach, but android studio complains about how `arrStr` may not have been intialized:

```
    String[] arrStr;

    switch (sensorType) {
        case "acc": {
            curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATA_ACC_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE id = " + subNum, null);
            arrStr = new String[]{curCSV.getString(0), curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2),curCSV.getString(3), curCSV.getString(4)};
            break;
        }
        case "gyro": {
            curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATA_GYRO_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE id = " + subNum, null);
            arrStr = new String[]{curCSV.getString(0), curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2),curCSV.getString(3), curCSV.getString(4)};
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Declare String arrStr[] above the switch case. In your code scope of arrStr is limited for  only in case block.

Comment: `String[] arrStr == null` fixes `may not have been intialized` warning

Comment: `String[] arrStr = {};` would be better. Also, @Vasily, you only want `=` here, not `==`.

Comment: @DavidConrad, of course `=`, just misspelling )

Comment: What will happen if `sensorType` is neither `acc` nor `gyro`? Also, you should be using `rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ? WHERE id = ?", new String[] { DATA_ACC_TABLE_NAME, subNum })` or just building the table names in and passing `subNum` as a query parameter. String concatenation for SQL queries is very bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to declare the array variable like this (outside the `switch`):

```
public void exportSubjectData(File outputFile, String subNum, String sensorType) throws IOException, SQLException {

    csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));

    String arrStr[] = null;

    switch (sensorType) {
        case "acc": {
            curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATA_ACC_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE id = " + subNum, null);
            arrStr = new String[] {curCSV.getString(0), curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2),
                    curCSV.getString(3), curCSV.getString(4)};
            break;
        }
        case "gyro": {
            curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATA_GYRO_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE id = " + subNum, null);
            arrStr = new String[] {curCSV.getString(0), curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2)};
            break;
        }
    }

    csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());

    while (curCSV.moveToNext()) {
        csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
    }

    csvWrite.close();
    curCSV.close();
}
```

Comment: I've tried a number of approaches, including this one, but I think theres a syntax problem which is the root issue. When I try this solution, android studio complains about an unexpected token around `arrStr[] = ...` in the switch cases

Comment: I've modified the answer, please check